# Image zoomed in

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Currently I'm making a new portfolio website for school but I have some problems with responsive images.

The problem is that the scaling is very weird on different resolutions. On 1920X1080 it is fine. But when I visit the site on my laptop it looks like the image is "zoomed in".

[image: Screenshot 1366X768 (Laptop)]

This is my code:

```css
/* GENERAL */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/* END OF GENERAL */

/* NAVBAR */
nav.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
/* END OF NAVBAR */

/* HOMEPAGE */
.homeContainer {
    background-image: url(/img/homepageDesk.png);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
/* END OF HOMEPAGE */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Portfolio - MAND</title>
    
    <!-- CSS Links -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
    <!-- NAVIGATION MENU -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Navbar title -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Navbar buttons -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Over mij</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projecten</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Stageblog</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 
            </ul>
            <!-- Navbar login (Float: right) -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- END OF NAVIGATION MENU -->    
    
    <!-- HOME CONTENT -->
    <div class="homeContainer">

    </div>
    <!-- END OF HOME CONTENT -->
</body>
</html>
```

The div where I put the image as a background is: "div class:"homeContainer" ".

Hopefully someone knows a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize background by `background-size` properties. In your case I suggest `cover`:

```
.homeContainer {
    background-image: url(/img/homepageDesk.png);
    background-size:cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

more information here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: Youre welcome. Please remind that `background-size` should be after `background-image`, elsewhere wont work in some browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code to this

```
/* HOMEPAGE */
.homeContainer {
  background-image: url(/img/homepageDesk.png) no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
}
/* END OF HOMEPAGE */
```